# Google Consumer Survey Example Survey Response Data

Tags: google-surveys

Is there any way to generate test Google Consumer Survey responses without running a real (paid) GCS Survey?

I'm building out an application for pulling, processing, and reporting GCS results. It's going to use [this](https://github.com/google/consumer-surveys/blob/master/python/src/example_client.py#L258) procedure for pulling the responses in Excel format, but I don't want to run a real survey just to test the module. Is there a procedure for doing this?

Note: Trying to pull responses from one of the example surveys found [here](https://www.google.com/insights/consumersurveys/examples) results in an authorization failure because the "User is not an owner of this survey".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I work on the Consumer Surveys team. You can access example survey results using the example surveys found under "Your Surveys": https://www.google.com/insights/consumersurveys/your-surveys?category=example.